# Setting max and min values on the graphic in the ZedGraph library

Tags: .net, image, graphics, image-processing, zedgraph

How to set max and min values manually on the Axis scale in the ZedGraph library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
chart.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
chart.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = 100;
```

If you set Min or Max, MinAuto and MaxAuto are automatically set to false.
Helpful: [Zedgraph-Documentation (API)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/files/zedgraph%20documentation/5.1.0%20+%204.6.0/)